# Mapbox android - How to add a text label to a custom marker icon?

Tags: android, xamarin, text, mapbox, marker

I am using Xamarin Android with Mapbox. I am trying to add a custom Marker (an image) and I need to place on top of that marker (if possible in the middle) a text / label. As I am only starting with Mapbox, I am wondering if this is possible ? Thx to all

Comment: no one has done it before ?

Comment: For those who are looking for the answer - follow the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496148/android-drawable-marker-with-bitmap-text-overlay-too-small